# MS Bot Framework Error: 'QnAMaker' does not contain a definition for 'CallTrainAsync' and no accessible extension method 'CallTrainAsync'

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to apply Active Learning to my chatbot using the Microsoft Bot Framework but I’m encountering an issue when I try to call the methods from the QnAMaker class required for active learning: GetLowScoreVariation() and CallTrainAsync().

```
    var filteredResponse = botServices.QnAServices[QnAMakerName].GetLowScoreVariation(response.ToArray()).ToList();


    await botServices.QnAServices[QnAMakerName].CallTrainAsync(feedbackRecords);
```

These two lines of code produce the errors "'QnAMaker' does not contain a definition for 'GetLowScoreVariation' and no accessible extension method 'GetLowScoreVariation' accepting a first argument of type 'QnAMaker' could be found" and "'QnAMaker' does not contain a definition for 'CallTrainAsync' and no accessible extension method 'CallTrainAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'QnAMaker' could be found":

I have included `using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA` (version 4.2.0 installed) and I am also using the GetAnswersAsync() method from the QnAMaker class (`var response = await botServices.QnAServices[QnAMakerName].GetAnswersAsync(stepContext.Context, qnaMakerOptions);`) and it is producing no errors. An ideas what is the issue here?

Comment: The above error might be due to the package issue as mentioned by Nicholas below. I would suggest you to refer to the qnamaker-active-learning-bot [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/48.qnamaker-active-learning-bot) which makes use of Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA version 4.6.3 and compare your existing code with that of the sample implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you are using 4.2.0 QnA package.

This package is quite old (december 2018), I'm not sure that Active Learning methods were available in the package at that time.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Ai.QnA/

Can you upgrade your package and check please?